# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'convert_to_tensor'

Tags: keras

I insatll tensorflow and keras in windows 7 and worked with them for a while. But today when I import keras I get an error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'convert_to_tensor'
Could somebody help me?

Comment: Can you give some more information about versions of keras/tensorflow and how you installed the packages (Anaconda / pip)?
One solution might be a reinstallation of tensorflow.

Comment: @Max HI. Thanks for your response. Well, the version of tensorflow is 2 and the version of keras is 2.3.1. I installed them  with both pip and conda. They worked well until next week but now I can't import them

Comment: Okay, have you installed tensorflow and keras separately? As keras comes with tensorflow 2.3.1, I would use only tensorflow.keras.
And generally, I would use only one package manager (either conda or pip).
If this doesn't work either, try to reinstall tensorflow with conda (conda install tensorflow --force-reinstall)

Comment: @max Thanks for your help.